# '::' must be a class or namespace name in another class

Tags: c++

I had defined a function in the header below

```
class Camera
{
public:
glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix()
   {
       return glm::lookAt(Position, Position + Front, Up);
   }
}
```

but when I use it in another class,it;s show.

Error (active)  E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

```
void Camera::glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix()
{
   return glm::lookAt(Position, Position + Front, Up);
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: That second snippet should be `glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewMatrix()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `glm` class in `Camera` class as shown. Change that function definition to `glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewMatrix()` instead.